# Is git merge and Atlassian pull request effectively the same?

Tags: bitbucket-server

My developer team is working on a big branch that aims to be merged into the develop branch in the future.

This big branch acts like a mini develop branch, so we practice the use of pull requests to update this mini develop branch (although our repository admin did not restrict directly committing into this mini develop branch).

However, we also frequently take in updates from the develop branch to the mini develop branch. The current practice (for code quality) is to just use `git merge` on local and `git push`, followed by having team members manually review the changes themselves after changes on the develop has been updated on the mini develop branch.

I was wondering whether submitting a Atlassian pull request (our team uses Atlassian) would do the same as `git merge` + `git push` but with the developers having to approve the pull request before merging on the remote. That would same me some effort having to beg team members to manually review the merge to check whether anything has gone wrong.

Comment: Hi @mason, sorry my bad, it was autosuggested

Comment: Git itself does not have pull requests. Most *hosting sites* (including GitHub and Bitbucket) have something like that. Git*Lab* calls it a "merge request". A pull or merge request is a system by which you ask someone else to do a merge for you; most hosting systems add a lot more "value" to this, over and above what you'd get by using `git request-pull` to generate an email message that you then send with `git send-email`.

Comment: I'm guessing here that you're using bitbucket or bitbucket-server, so that would be the tag to use here.